# How to check AccessRight in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to pass username and accessrights to check with get-acl if anybody knows please advice. i have tried with below command but i am not satisfied with that.

```
$AccessRule = $path.Access | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -like "*\$username"}
if($AccessRule){
    $AccessRights = $path.Access | Where-Object {$_.FileSystemRights -like '$AccessRight'}
    if($Accessrights){
        write-output "Success"
    }
    else{
        write-output "failed"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but this really isn't a very good question. "if anyone knows" _what_? You're "not satisfied with that" - what is _that_ and _why_ doesn't it satisfy you? What is `$path`? What is `$AccessRight`? And most importantly, _what are you trying to achieve_?

Comment: I am using two where-object  for checking but that's not good. i looking for code efficiency for my view this not correct way to check we have some other option. $path = Directorypath would like check(C:\script) $Accessright = user given input(read,write,modify,fullcontrol)

Comment: It looks like [this](https://github.com/rohnedwards/TestAcl) module might work for you. If I'm understanding what you're asking, you'd want to use it like this: `Test-Acl c:\script -RequiredAccess 'UserName Read, Write'`. If that's what you're looking for, I can create a better answer (and even describe how to do it without the module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not share with us why you are not satisfied.

**Edit** based on comment
How about this code?  Is it better?

```
$Path = 'c:\<your paths>'
$get_acl = (Get-Acl $path).Access
ForEach ($acl_record in $get_acl) {
    If (($acl_record.IdentityReference -eq "*\$username") -And ($acl_record.FileSystemRights -eq "$AccessRight")) ) {
          Write-Host "For the $Path the user" $acl_record.IdentityReference " has access!"
      }
  }
```

Comment: I need check FileSystemRights(as per user input) as well please suggest Thanks.

Comment: @vel like for multiple users at once?

Comment: @vel I have edited the answer based on your comment is that better?

Comment: Thank you tukan.!

Comment: @vel if you really like it you can even upvote it ;).